# Spark Sql UDF throwing NullPointer when adding a filter on a columns that uses that UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

SPARK_VERSION = 2.2.0

I ran into an interesting issue when trying to do a `filter` on a dataframe that has columns that were added using a UDF. I am able to replicate the problem with a smaller set of data.

Given the dummy case classes:

```
case class Info(number: Int, color: String)
case class Record(name: String, infos: Seq[Info])
```

and the following data:

```
val blue = Info(1, "blue")
val black = Info(2, "black")
val yellow = Info(3, "yellow")
val orange = Info(4, "orange")
val white = Info(5, "white")

val a  = Record("a", Seq(blue, black, white))
val a2 = Record("a", Seq(yellow, white, orange))
val b = Record("b", Seq(blue, black))
val c = Record("c", Seq(white, orange))
val d = Record("d", Seq(orange, black))
```

do the following...

Create two dataframes (we will call them left and right)

```
val left = Seq(a, b).toDF
val right = Seq(a2, c, d).toDF
```

Join those dataframes using a `full_outer` join, and take only what is on the right side

```
val rightOnlyInfos  = left.alias("l")
  .join(right.alias("r"), Seq("name"), "full_outer")
  .filter("l.infos is null")
  .select($"name", $"r.infos".as("r_infos"))
```

This results in the following:

```
rightOnlyInfos.show(false)
+----+-----------------------+
|name|r_infos                |
+----+-----------------------+
|c   |[[5,white], [4,orange]]|
|d   |[[4,orange], [2,black]]|
+----+-----------------------+
```

Using the following udf, add a new column that is a boolean and represents whether or not one of the `r_infos` contains the color `black`

```
def hasBlack = (s: Seq[Row]) => {
  s.exists{ case Row(num: Int, color: String) =>
    color == "black"
  }
}

val joinedBreakdown = rightOnlyInfos.withColumn("has_black", udf(hasBlack).apply($"r_infos"))
```

This is where I am seeing problems now. If I do the following, I get no errors:

```
joinedBreakdown.show(false)
```

and it results (like expected) in:

```
+----+-----------------------+---------+
|name|r_infos                |has_black|
+----+-----------------------+---------+
|c   |[[5,white], [4,orange]]|false    |
|d   |[[4,orange], [2,black]]|true     |
+----+-----------------------+---------+
```

and the schema

```
joinedBreakdown.printSchema
```

shows

```
root 
  |-- name: string (nullable = true) 
  |-- r_infos: array (nullable = true) 
  | |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
  | | |-- number: integer (nullable = false) 
  | | |-- color: string (nullable = true)
  |-- has_black: boolean (nullable = true)
```

However, when I try to filter by that results, I get an error:

```
joinedBreakdown.filter("has_black == true").show(false)
```

With the following error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$hasBlack$1: (array<struct<number:int,color:string>>) => boolean)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF.eval(ScalaUDF.scala:1075)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BinaryExpression.eval(Expression.scala:411)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.EliminateOuterJoin.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$optimizer$EliminateOuterJoin$$canFilterOutNull(joins.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.EliminateOuterJoin$$anonfun$rightHasNonNullPredicate$lzycompute$1$1.apply(joins.scala:138)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.EliminateOuterJoin$$anonfun$rightHasNonNullPredicate$lzycompute$1$1.apply(joins.scala:138)
  at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.exists(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:93)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.exists(List.scala:84)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.EliminateOuterJoin.rightHasNonNullPredicate$lzycompute$1(joins.scala:138)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.EliminateOuterJoin.rightHasNonNullPredicate$1(joins.scala:138)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.EliminateOuterJoin.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$optimizer$EliminateOuterJoin$$buildNewJoinType(joins.scala:145)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.EliminateOuterJoin$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(joins.scala:152)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.EliminateOuterJoin$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(joins.scala:150)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:267)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:267)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:266)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:272)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:272)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:272)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:256)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.EliminateOuterJoin.apply(joins.scala:150)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.EliminateOuterJoin.apply(joins.scala:116)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:85)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:82)
  at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:124)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:82)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:74)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:74)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:78)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:78)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:84)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:80)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:89)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:89)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:2832)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2153)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2366)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:245)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:646)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:623)
  ... 58 elided
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at $anonfun$hasBlack$1.apply(<console>:41)
  at $anonfun$hasBlack$1.apply(<console>:40)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF$$anonfun$2.apply(ScalaUDF.scala:92)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF$$anonfun$2.apply(ScalaUDF.scala:91)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF.eval(ScalaUDF.scala:1072)
  ... 114 more
```

**EDIT:** opened up a jira issue. Pasting here for tracking purposes:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22942

Comment: Doesn't `filter` take a String or a Column expression? Shouldn't it either be `$"has_black" === lit(true)` or `"has_black = true"` ?

Comment: @philantrovert both of those work, and both still produce the error message.

Comment: I think what the issue is has to do with order of operations as to when the UDF is getting called by the optimizer.

When calling `joinedBreakdown.show(false)`, the UDF was run post join and filter (so there are no nulls). When calling `joinedBreakdown.filter("has_black == true").show(false)`, the UDF is called pre join / filter, so there could be nulls.

Comment: Interesting comment in the Jira issue that you created.

"Since spark passes null to udfs in optimizer rules, you need to make udfs null-safe."

So I also had similar random issues with UDFs with other operations.
 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22942?focusedCommentId=16309037&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-16309037

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer doesn't address why the issue exists but solutions that I have found to work around it.

I have run into a problem exactly like this. I'm not sure of the cause but I have two workarounds that work for me. Someone much smarter than me will probably be able to explain it all to you but here are my solutions to the problem.

**FIRST SOLUTION**

Spark is acting like the column doesn't exist yet. Probably because of some kind of filter push-down. Force Spark to cache the result prior to filtering. This makes the column "exist".

```
val joinedBreakdown = rightOnlyInfos.withColumn("has_black", hasBlack($"r_infos")).cache()
println(joinedBreakdown.count()) //This will force cache the results from after the UDF has been applied.
joinedBreakdown.filter("has_black == true").show(false)
joinedBreakdown.filter("has_black == true").explain
```

OUTPUT

```
2
+----+-----------------------+---------+
|name|r_infos                |has_black|
+----+-----------------------+---------+
|d   |[[4,orange], [2,black]]|true     |
+----+-----------------------+---------+
== Physical Plan ==
*Filter (has_black#112632 = true)
+- InMemoryTableScan [name#112622, r_infos#112628, has_black#112632], [(has_black#112632 = true)]
      +- InMemoryRelation [name#112622, r_infos#112628, has_black#112632], true, 10000, StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
            +- *Project [coalesce(name#112606, name#112614) AS name#112622, infos#112615 AS r_infos#112628, UDF(infos#112615) AS has_black#112632]
               +- *Filter isnull(infos#112607)
                  +- SortMergeJoin [name#112606], [name#112614], FullOuter
                     :- *Sort [name#112606 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
                     :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(name#112606, 200)
                     :     +- LocalTableScan [name#112606, infos#112607]
                     +- *Sort [name#112614 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
                        +- Exchange hashpartitioning(name#112614, 200)
                           +- LocalTableScan [name#112614, infos#112615]
```

**SECOND SOLUTION**

No idea why this one works, but do the same thing that you did except put a try/catch in the UDF. And before I get yelled at for it, please know that using try/catch for control flow is an anit-pattern. To learn more I recommend this [question and answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why). NOTE: I edited your UDF slightly to make it look like something that I am more familiar with.

```
def hasBlack = udf((s: Seq[Row]) => {
  try{
    s.exists{ case Row(num: Int, color: String) =>
      color == "black"
    }
  } catch {
    case ex: Exception => false
  }
})

val joinedBreakdown = rightOnlyInfos.withColumn("has_black", hasBlack($"r_infos"))
joinedBreakdown.filter("has_black == true").explain
joinedBreakdown.filter("has_black == true").show(false)
```

OUTPUT

```
== Physical Plan ==
*Project [coalesce(name#112565, name#112573) AS name#112581, infos#112574 AS r_infos#112587, UDF(infos#112574) AS has_black#112591]
+- *Filter isnull(infos#112566)
   +- *BroadcastHashJoin [name#112565], [name#112573], RightOuter, BuildLeft, false
      :- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(ArrayBuffer(input[0, string, false]))
      :  +- *Filter isnotnull(name#112565)
      :     +- LocalTableScan [name#112565, infos#112566]
      +- *Filter (UDF(infos#112574) = true)
         +- LocalTableScan [name#112573, infos#112574]
+----+-----------------------+---------+
|name|r_infos                |has_black|
+----+-----------------------+---------+
|d   |[[4,orange], [2,black]]|true     |
+----+-----------------------+---------+
```

You can see that the query plans are different due to the fact that I am forcing the application of the UDF prior to the filter.

Comment: Correct, all of these solutions work. Interestingly, when you change 

`val rightOnlyInfos  = left.alias("l")
  .join(right.alias("r"), Seq("name"), "full_outer")
  .filter("l.infos is null")
  .select($"name", $"r.infos".as("r_infos"))`

to

`val rightOnlyInfos  = left.alias("l")
  .join(right.alias("r"), Seq("name"), "full_outer")
  .filter("l.infos is null and r.infos is not null")
  .select($"name", $"r.infos".as("r_infos"))`

It works.

Weird because `l.infos is null` should be equal to `l.infos is null and r.infos is not null` on an outer join